# how to get the drop point lat and lng in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Here I had added my some basic google map with a marker, What I need is get the drop point `Lat` and `Lng` position in Google map. I had integrated the google map in react JS Components.

```
initializeMap(){
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(13.083432624993291, 80.27261740398262);
    var dragOn = true;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 16,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      draggable: dragOn 
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    }, 1000);
}

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD_iFsNeNE2pqOUE86VFrvecTZQqyEb7ic&libraries=places"></script>
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  function initializeMap() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(13.083432624993291, 80.27261740398262);
    var dragOn = true;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 16,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      draggable: dragOn
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
      marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    }, 1000);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {
           alert( 'Lat: ' + event.latLng.lat() + ' and Longitude is: ' + event.latLng.lng() );
        });
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initializeMap"></script>
```

this is the google map libraries I had used. I tried out with this code but not working properly. can anyone help me with this

Comment: What do you mean by "drop point"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `dragend` event and add it to your marker like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {
   alert( 'Lat: ' + event.latLng.lat() + ' and Longitude is: ' + event.latLng.lng() );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

for get the "drop point"  .. i assume the lat, lng of the position where you click on map you can use a listerner that manage the event (passed  as e in this sample)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {
     console.log( e.latLng.lat());
     console.log( e.latLng.lng());
});
```

you can see the result in your browser  console  .. or use alert(e.latLng.lat()) forn open a test window